# Plot subset of netcdf in R using lat/lon boundaries

Tags: r, latitude-longitude, subset, netcdf

I have a netcdf file in R with 14 variables that I would like to subset using latitude and longitude boundaries i.e. extract some of the variables for specific ocean regions. So far I've been trying for the South Pacific (between -150W and -90W and between -60S and 0S).

The file details are as follows (code below just shows details of first variable "bio1"):

```
"File oceandata.nc (NC_FORMAT_CLASSIC):"
14 variables (excluding dimension variables):"
float bio1[lon,lat]   "
standard_name: air_temperature"
long_name: bio1: Annual Mean Temp"
units: C"
_FillValue: 1.00000001504747e+30"
valid_max: 307.259399414062"
valid_min: 226.706176757812"
```

I have used the following code:

```
require(ncdf4)
oceana = nc_open( "oceandata.nc" )
LatIdx = which ( oceana$dim$lat$vals < 0 & oceana$dim$lat$vals < -60)
LonIdx = which ( oceana$dim$lon$vals > -150 & oceana$dim$lon$vals < -90)
myvariable <- ncvar_get( oceana, "bio1")[ LonIdx, LatIdx]
lon <- ncvar_get(oceana, "lon")
lat <- ncvar_get(oceana, "lat")
```

However when I try to plot using:

```
image(lon,lat, myvariable)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in image.default(lon, lat, myvariable) :
```

increasing 'x' and 'y' values expected

Any comments/suggestions on where I'm going wrong here would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you include the link to download the netcdf file if publicly available? This would make your code repeatable and thus easier to diagnose.

Comment: Can you include what `lon` and `lat` look like?

Answer (score 0):

`image` requires the `x` and `y` parameters to have increasing values. I suspect that your `lat` and `lon` values are decreasing (i.e. -90W to -150W). If so, consider switching the order.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I have tried reversing the the syntax for "LonIdx" i.e. to:

Comment: LonIdx = which ( oceana$dim$lon$vals > -90 & oceana$dim$lon$vals < -150) but still returns the same error message. Is this what you meant by switching the order or rather switch the order of the "lon" and "lat" vars themselves? Thanks very much for the help, Amy